# ModelState always valid

Tags: asp.net, validation, asp.net-mvc-2, modelstate

I've got something seemingly very simple not working.

I have got a model

```
public class Name: Entity
{
    [StringLength(10), Required]
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
}

public class Customer: Entity
{
    public virtual Name Name { get; set; }
}
```

a view model

```
public class CustomerViweModel
{
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

a view

```
       <% using(Html.BeginForm()) { %>
                    <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.Customer.Name.Title)%>
                    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer.Name.Title)%> 
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        <% } %>
```

and a controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index([Bind(Prefix = "Customer")] Customer customer)
{
      if(ModelState.IsValid)
           Save
       else
           return View();
 }
```

No matter what I enter as the title (null, or a string > 10 chars), ModelState.IsValid is always true.  The Title field in the Customer object has a value, so the data is being passed around, but not being validated?

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, it was becuase I'm referencing System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations 3.6 instead of 3.5.  From what I gather, 3.6 is for WCF RIA services only.

Answer (score 5):

In your View I don't see any text box or a field allowing to send data to the controller, only a label. Properties will [not be validated if they are not posted](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/01/input-validation-vs-model-validation-in-aspnet-mvc.html). Add a textbox, leave it blank and your model won't be valid any more:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer.Name.Title)%>
```

---

UPDATE:

Here's the code I've used:

Model:

```
public class Name
{
    [StringLength(10), Required]
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public virtual Name Name { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerViewModel
{
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index([Bind(Prefix = "Customer")]Customer cs)
    {
        return View(new CustomerViewModel
        {
            Customer = cs
        });
    }
}
```

View:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyApp.Models.CustomerViewModel>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <% using(Html.BeginForm()) { %>
        <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.Customer.Name.Title)%>
        <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer.Name.Title)%> 
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    <% } %>
</asp:Content>
```

When you submit this form a validation error is shown.

Remark1: I've omitted the `Entity` base class in the models as I don't how does it look.

Remark2: I've renamed the variable in the Index action to `cs`. I remember that there was some problems with this in ASP.NET MVC 1.0 when you had the prefix and the variable named the same but I am not sure whether this applies here and I think it was fixed.

Comment: My bad, I do have a textbox in the view.

Comment: Well, I've just tried this example and it worked as expected, validation errors were shown for the title property.