# null reference in ASP.NET MVC 5 identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am having a problem with the ASP.NET MVC Individuel user accounts default template. I get null reference at ActionResult Register but the modelstate is valid.  I have created an other project with the same code and it works like a charm.

In this project it doensn't work this is my code can you please help me.

**My models:**

```
     public class User : IdentityUser
    {
        //public string Title { get; set; } // mevr. of mr.
        //public string FirstName { get; set; }
        //public string LastName { get; set; }
        //public System.DateTime? Birthdate { get; set; }

        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<User> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
```

**DbContext class (for EF migrations)**

```
    public class PortLoginContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
    {
        public PortLoginContext()
                : base("PortOfTroyLogin", throwIfV1Schema: false)
            {
            }

        public static PortLoginContext Create()
            {
                return new PortLoginContext();
            }

            protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

                modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("User").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");
                modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRole");
                modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogin");
                modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaim").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserClaimId");
                modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Role").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("RoleId");

            }
```

**My controller**

```
     [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new User { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email}; //Username & Email fills correctly
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password); //Password fills correctly
                if (result.Succeeded) //Here is the null reference :(
                {
                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                    // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                    // Send an email with this link
                    // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                    // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                    // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }

Thank you for your help
```

***UPDATE*** 
**Posted Register Viewmodel**

```
    public class RegisterViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

**My views for extra information:**

```
@model PortOfTroy.Models.RegisterViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" />
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**UPDATE THE GOOD ONE!!!** 
**Stack trace**

```
[NullReferenceException: De objectverwijzing is niet op een exemplaar van een object ingesteld.]
   PortOfTroy.Controllers.<Register>d__f.MoveNext() in c:\Users\Gamer\Source\Workspaces\SAMGOwebproject\Leerjaar 2\PortOfTroy\PortOfTroy\Controllers\AccountController.cs:155
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +21
   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.ThrowIfFaulted(Task task) +61
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +114
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +66
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +117
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +323
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +72
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +185
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9651116
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ModelState always valid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659127/modelstate-always-valid)

Comment: Please post the RegisterViewModel

Comment: Post the stack trace?

Comment: @RameshRajendran Thank you for your post, but there is nothing wrong with my View. Just to be sure I added it to my question

Comment: Where is your Login action method? That's what you point to in your form and what is shown in your stacktrace

Comment: @JeroenVannevel sorry wrong stacktrace here is the  stacktrace of the Register method!

Comment: Do you have any custom implementation on the `UserManager` or is it default provided by AspNet.Identity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oke I finally solved it (with some help of you guys). I had some custom implementations in my public class User : IdentityUser I did comment them out but I didn't do the same in my Viewmodels Register and Login! So yeah the model expected some data that wasn't there anymore. I want to thank @Jake he came up with the custom implementation on the UserManager.

Comment: Yeah if you use Entity Framework on this. then you just can add a new migration and that will also solve the problem.